# Flutter app wont run after changing app name in podfile.lock

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

My app was working perfectly before but then I changed its display name now when I try to run it on my ios emulator i get this error:

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): None of the input catalogs contained a matching stickers icon set or app icon set named  "AppIcon".
/Users/../ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets
```

Answer (score 0):

Editing below values in ios>Runner>info.plist is right way to change app name.

```
// old
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>OldAppName</string>
// new
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>NewAppName</string>
```

Comment: thats exactly how i did it

Comment: Hit flutter clean then flutter pub upgrade @Russeljones

Comment: I did that too and its the same result

Comment: @Russeljones Can you send the GitHub link of code?